# inApp purchase, dowload free products

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I am implementing inApp features with download hosted content feature. All products are free for unlimited time. Each product have one download associated and that is audio file.

1. Is possible to start download without user see dialog to buy free product. First user must give his apple id password, than he see dialog to buy free product and than dialog that product is succesfully purchased.Than download can be requested.
   But since all products are free can somehow download be reuested without user see confiramtion dialogs and messages and start download imedietly.
2. If item was previously be purchased/downloaded than user see message that will buy free item again. I know for restore functionalities, but do I need to track previously downloaded items and in that case start download from restore state.

Thanks!

Comment: why do you need in-app-purchase for free items

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes, You can download without dialogs. get product detail using store kit, and if product price is free (0), download  item without processing purchase request from Storekit.

Code to request product detail:

```
KProductsRequest *productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers: [NSSet setWithArray:productIdentifiers]];

// Keep a strong reference to the request.
self.request = productsRequest;
productsRequest.delegate = self;
[productsRequest start];
```

// SKProductsRequestDelegate protocol method

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request
     didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    self.products = response.products;

    for (NSString *invalidIdentifier in response.invalidProductIdentifiers) {
        // Handle any invalid product identifiers. or check that product you are looking for dozens has its identifier here

    }
    for (SKProduct *product in self.products) 
    {
         //for example, product you are looking for has identifier  "com.product.free"          
         if([product.productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"com.product.free"] && [product.price compareWithInt:0])
         {
               // Startdownloading without purchase  
         }

    }
}
```

2) If you have non-consumable inappt purchase, you must provide option for restore. for downloading, you can write your own logic. check if item is downloaded and re-download only if its not available.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I understand everything but I am not clear how to start doanload without SKPaymentQueue and payments which are causing inApp dialogs?  Or how to start download from productRequest didReceiveResponse method. I am not sure that this is possible.
Can you please provide a bit more code how to start download. My code works but must add payments to payment queue and obtain updatedTransactions where I can request downloads. But in that case system inApp dialogs/alerts appear. Thanks! :]

Comment: @NikolaJovic for downloading it without inapp purchase dialog, your content must be hosted as on-Demand resources. You can assign tag to content which you want to download with this purchase and you can initiate downloading  NSBundleResourceRequest . https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/Managing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015083-CH4-SW1